# static value in a form

Tags: php, html, post

I have a form with list of fields :

- last name
- email
- country
- message

Before sending the form, i want to joint to it a static value : destination=marketing.
i don't want it to be visible in my form. how would this be done ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Input hidden is what you need :

```
<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="marketing" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="marketing" />
```

or you can add this variable when you process the form server-side

Answer (score 1):

With a hidden input. Or put it in the session instead.